# Change background color of boxes with .addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the background color of some boxes to change While the pointer is hovered over it in js but not having any luck. Here's the js

```
var box = document.getElementByClassName("box");

box.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = "#aad9f1";
});
box.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = "#9Ac9e1";
});
```

Here's the css for the box class

```
.box{
  height: 25px;
  width: 14.25%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #9Ac9e1;
  float: left;
  font-size: 130%;
}
```

And the boxes in the html file

```
    <div class="menubar_box">
      <div class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/microphones.html">Microphones</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/preamps.html">Preamps</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/compressors.html">Compressors</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/equalizers.html">Equalizers</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/instruments.html">Instruments</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></div>
    </div>
```

I've also linked the app.js in the index.html, nothing happens though when I mouseover the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for typos, and iterate through elements:

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#aad9f1";
  });
  box[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#9Ac9e1";
  });
}
```

```css
.box{
  height: 25px;
  width: 14.25%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #9Ac9e1;
  float: left;
  font-size: 130%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menubar_box">
      <div class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/microphones.html">Microphones</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/preamps.html">Preamps</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/compressors.html">Compressors</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/equalizers.html">Equalizers</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/instruments.html">Instruments</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></div>
    </div>
```

But what you can do is putting the `hover` rule in CSS:

```css
.box{
  height: 25px;
  width: 14.25%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #9Ac9e1;
  float: left;
  font-size: 130%;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #aad9f1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
    <div class="menubar_box">
      <div class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/microphones.html">Microphones</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/preamps.html">Preamps</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/compressors.html">Compressors</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/equalizers.html">Equalizers</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/instruments.html">Instruments</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="pages/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I got the .box:hover to work. Could I also make size of the box swell using this method? The js method didn't work for me. Would I have to have an array of boxes for this to work. Sorry for the noob questions

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the "swell" effect you'd like. The JS method works as I've written above, just run the snippet to see it.
And don't forget to check my answer as resolved!

Comment: Also, is there a parameter for it to gradually swell, instead of it being instantaneous?

Comment: It's not instantaneous, it takes 0.2 seconds in my example. Change this parameter if you want it to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues... One you are using `getElementByClassName` should be => `getElementsByClassName` note the plural use of `Elements` second you have a list of elements to query over, therefor you need to reference the key of the selector. In the example below I use `querySelectorAll()` to create a `nodeList` then I wrap the code in a `forEach` loop to iterate over the `nodelist` and find the value of the element being selected.

**NOTE:** *`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTML collection`, so `forEach` will not work with it, as another user pointed out in their answer you can use a `for` loop and iterate through with the value of the iterator or counter as a key indicator. `for(let i = 0; i < box.length; i++)` then in the loop you find the element out fo the collection using the iterator => `i`.*

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
box.forEach((value, index) => {
  box[index].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    value.style.backgroundColor = "#aad9f1";
    value.style.cssText = 'transform: scale(1.2);'
  });
  box[index].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    value.style.backgroundColor = "#9Ac9e1";
    value.style.cssText = 'transform: scale(1);'
  });
})
```

```css
.menubar_box {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #9Ac9e1;
  font-size: 130%;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center; 
  justify-content:center;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar_box">
  <div class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/microphones.html">Microphones</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/preamps.html">Preamps</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/compressors.html">Compressors</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/equalizers.html">Equalizers</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/instruments.html">Instruments</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="pages/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I would also like for the boxes to get larger when the pointer is hovering over them. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Adding the display flex to the parent element, allows you to remove the float and also control other aspects of alignment in the child element. I also added width of 100% so the menu stretches across the parent elements width, then a bit of padding to the divs to cushion the display and look more fluid.

Comment: You can add a transform to the css using JS as well, though as another user pointed out, this can be placed directly in your css using the psuedo `;hover` property

Answer (score 0):

You should swap out `document.getElementByClassName("box")` (which has a typo) for `document.querySelectorAll(".box")`. This method is much more reusable if you need to select elements with a given class, id, tag, etc.

When you use this method, `boxes` will be an array of all elements that match the selector. So you have to apply your logic to each of them. The `forEach` method is best for this.

Here's a working example:

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#aad9f1";
  });
  
  box.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#9Ac9e1";
  });
})
```

```css
.box{
     height: 25px;
     width: 14.25%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     border: 0px solid black;
     background-color: #9Ac9e1;
     float: left;
     font-size: 130%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="menubar_box">
    <div class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="box"><a href="pages/microphones.html">Microphones</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="pages/preamps.html">Preamps</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="pages/compressors.html">Compressors</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="pages/equalizers.html">Equalizers</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="pages/instruments.html">Instruments</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="pages/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></div>
 </div>
```